# Force Facebook to ask user password when using OpenGraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I use Facebook OAuth 2.0 to register new users to my website. After which they can also login using Facebook.

If a user is already logged in at Facebook, and registers at my site, I would like Facebook to ask again for the password of the current user so I know for sure the user that registers is the person logged in at Facebook. Because often home-computers are being used my multiple people, and people tend not to logout from Facebook.

Comment: If your site really needs to be that secure, I would suggest using some sort of secondary authentication system. One suggestion would be to retrieve the user's email address. You can access this by asking for the 'email' extended permission. Once you have the email address, just send them a verification link. Only, after they click the link would you allow them access to your site.

Comment: It's not about security, it's about our Joe Average not paying attention to the Facebook popup dialog (in the left bottom it says "Not Jane Doe, click here."), and signing up to my website, with the Facebook account of Jane Doe (who was still logged in to Facebook).

Comment: I only care about this during registration (using facebook), for logging in, I want the default behavior (make log in a one click action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's up to Facebook to decide when to prompt the user for password, not you. You can always put up an additional prompt asking the user to confirm who they are later.

Comment: Was already afraid of that, since I couldn't find any reference to it. Yet was quietly hoping for it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net and C#(Facebook API's For .NET available on codeplex.com),

Add this line in the Page_PreInit Event

```
      base.RequireLogin=true;
```

If the user is logged in, it will not ask for the login, but if the user it not logged in, it will redirect to you the Facebook login page.

Comment: That is not correct. This will still behave the way he is trying to avoid. What he is asking to do is not possible.